# Connecting to Zend Debugger on remote server

Tags: shared-hosting, zend-debugger

I am having great difficulty  connecting to the zend debugger on a dreamhost account.
I get the following error message.

> Failed to connect to host '192.168.11.7'. Failed to connect to host '192.168.56.1'. Failed to connect to host '127.0.0.1'.

Is this a problem with the debugger not being able to connect to my local machine? Do I need to forward a port on my router perhaps?

I have also added my external ip to the allowed hosts but to no avail.

Any hints much appreciated,
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is XDebug enable on Dreamhost - not sure it is.  You can port forward using an SSH shell, [Check here](http://onlamp.com/pub/a/onlamp/excerpt/ssh_11/index3.html)